# Express.js keeps serving Angular2 index.html as text

Tags: node.js, express, angular

I can't seem to use Express.js to serve up my frontend Angular2 app. It just keeps serving index.html as text and the scripts don't appear to load.

## Steps to reproduce:

```
npm install angular-cli -g
ng new ng2app && cd ng2app
npm install express --save && npm install
touch src/server.js
```

**update server.js file**

```
// src/server.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

**Run the server**

```
node src/server.js
# => Node app is running on port 5000
```

**http://localhost:5000/**

---

## Problem

browser spits this out on the page and never does anything (i.e it doesn't load my front-end angular2 app)

> {{#unless environment.production}} {{/unless}} Loading... {{#each scripts.polyfills}}{{/each}}

also on this page there are the following browser console errors

> GET http://localhost:5000/ember-cli-live-reload.js
>
> (index):19 GET http://localhost:5000/%7B%7B.%7D%7D
>
> (index):21 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined

---

What am I doing wrong? P.S there's nothing wrong with the angular front-end portion. I know this because doing `npm start` works and ng2app loads up just fine like its supposed to.

Comment: Do you want Express to basically do the same as `npm start`, or do you want Express to run the built app (the result from `ng build`)?

Comment: What i want is to host the angular2 app on Heroku. To do that i need a Procfile with ```web: node src/server.js``` command in it (also will need to do several other configuration steps but this is the one i'm hung up on). By my reasoning, this command should work for me in dev console so that I can see what it will do in production. What i expect it to do is allow me to view/interact with my angular app in the browser (the same way npm start lets me view and interact with the app in the browser). It doesnt. It just renders text of my index.html page. How can i get it to behave like npm start?

Comment: "Not easily", by the looks of it (as it looks like it has a lot of moving parts). It seems pretty easy to get a _built_ version served through Express, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimum that I have from a seed project see: https://github.com/spboyer/quickstart-ng-cli

```
var express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var staticRoot = __dirname + '/';
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));
app.use(express.static(staticRoot));
app.use(function(req, res, next){
// if the request is not html then move along
var accept = req.accepts('html', 'json', 'xml');
if(accept !== 'html'){
    return next();
}
// if the request has a '.' assume that it's for a file, move along
var ext = path.extname(req.path);
if (ext !== ''){
    return next();
}
fs.createReadStream(staticRoot + 'index.html').pipe(res);
});
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
console.log('app running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

To me it looks like you have not actually ran the angular cli build.